# How to make an <ng-template>component</ng-template> replace another on the exact same page space

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap@3 classes to vertically split the page in a col-md-5 and a col-md-7 (for a total of 12).

My goal is: after clicking on the "new recipe" button, to have  replace  on the same area (on the right beside .

Unfortunately, the  component comes on the bottom, like it take a new row.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <app-recipe-list  ></app-recipe-list>           

</div>

<div class="col-md-7" *ngIf="this.recipesService.detailsOverNew; else details">
    <app-recipe-detail></app-recipe-detail>       
</div> 

<ng-template class="col-md-7" #details >
    <app-new-recipe></app-new-recipe>
</ng-template>
```

**Before i click on the button:**

[image: Before i push the button]

**After clicking:** (the form is under the list instead of its right side)

[image]

The content of

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2> New Recipe</h2>
        <div class="col-md-5">
                <input class="form-control" #newRecipeName placeholder="Name"> 
                <input class="form-control" #newRecipeDescription Description placeholder="Description">
                <input class="form-control" #newRecipePicture placeholder="Picture link">
        </div>
        
        
        
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Please show the content of `<app-new-recipe>`. And remove `class="col-md-7"` from your `#details` template

Comment: I added the content at the bottom of the original post.
Btw, <ng-template> elements do not accept classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you check the DOM to better understand what's going on.

When `this.recipesService.detailsOverNew` is not null,

```
<div class="col-md-7" *ngIf="this.recipesService.detailsOverNew; else details">
    <app-recipe-detail></app-recipe-detail>       
</div>
```

will render:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <app-recipe-detail></app-recipe-detail>       
</div>
```

Otherwise it will just render:

```
<app-new-recipe></app-new-recipe>
```

As you should notice, the class added in `<ng-template class="col-md-7" #details>` is useless.

A quick fix could be:

```
<ng-template #details >
   <div class="col-md-7"> <app-new-recipe></app-new-recipe> </div>
</ng-template>
```